# Android ContentProvider selection parameter of the delete method equal 1

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        int rowsDeleted;
        // this makes delete all rows return the number of rows deleted
        if ( null == selection ) selection = "1";
        switch (match) {
            case WEATHER:
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                        WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case LOCATION:
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                        WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        // Because a null deletes all rows
        if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
        return rowsDeleted;
    }
```

in the above code, why we should set the selection parameter to 1 if it is null to makes delete all rows return the number of rows deleted ?

what happens if we set the selection to another number or just keep it null ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing 1 as the selection parameter will delete all rows and return the deleted rows count whereas if the selection clause is Null it will still delete all rows but returns 0 as a result.

What happens when you pass any other number than 1 or 0 is not documented. You can experiment passing those numbers and logging the results to check what happens.

Check the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))